# Checking checkboxes

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to check if the user has checked more than one box.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
    else if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
```

The problem with the way I have it is it only shows the message box if the user checks the first checkbox then if they select the second one the messagebox.show comes up. But if the user selects the second and third the message doesnt show up.

I do understand I can do it the way I have below but I think there is a better way with less code. Because by doing it the way I have below the message pops up twice if checkbox 2 is checked.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
    else if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
    else if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
```

Comment: why don't you try a radio button list - it allows only one selection!

Comment: You should really consider using curly braces for making your code more readable... Also, makes it harder to make mistakes!

Comment: I didnt add all the code of the complete application I just put in the parts I am asking help with.

Comment: I concur.  Radio Buttons are what you want.  If you name checkboxes and/or radio buttons with the same name, libraries like jQuery, dojo, prototype, etc., can help you easily get the selected value without having to specify each checkbox or radio button individually if that's why you've avoided radio buttons.

Comment: I agree with PaulStack and Kevin Nelson:- Radiobuttons are designed for this kind of functionality. Unless you actually need to allow for multiple selections you should convert to using radiobuttons.

Comment: I went with Radio buttons thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int totalChecked =   (checkBox1.checked ? 1 : 0) + (checkBox2.checked ? 1 : 0)
                  + (checkBox3.checked ? 1 : 0);

if (totalChecked != 1)
  MessageBox.Show("Please select one car type");
```

Or as a commenter pointed out, use a radio button (which allows at most one selection).

Comment: Problem with this: You need to alter the code if there are more Checkboxes to be added.

Comment: It can easily be adapted to a list of checkboxes (filled perhaps by the tags on controls).

Comment: the more checkboxes - the more maintenance - the more bugs

Comment: Not really - just tag the checkboxes you want handled with a suitable constant. You're going to *have* to have some method of identifying the checkboxes you want to validate. Just checking all of them is a poor idea, even just checking those that are children of a given control. There may be other checkboxes that are not part of the "Only allow one selection" logic.

Comment: +1 if they are dead set on checkboxes something like this is going to be your best bet...cries out for radio buttons as already pointed out, however

Comment: But with the list, selected by a method, wouldn't that be similar to my proposal then?

Comment: No, because you're just finding every checkbox. You need to filter that result by something (i.e. a tag), in which case  you can use something like your code to locate and filter the checkboxes to build the list. Moreover, your code below isn't quite right - you're checking "At least one is checked", whereas he wants "Exactly one is checked".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a WPF Question

You can walk the logical tree and then check all checkboxes:

```
public bool IsAtLeastOneCheckboxChecked(DependencyObject rootObject)
{
    var checkboxes = FindLogicalChildrenOfType<CheckBox>(rootObject);
    foreach (var checkbox in checkboxes)
    {
        if (checkbox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FindLogicalChildrenOfType<T>(DependencyObject rootElement) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (rootElement != null)
    {
        var list = new List<DependencyObject>(LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(rootElement).OfType<DependencyObject>());
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item != null && item is T)
            {
                yield return (T)item;
            }

            foreach (var childOfChild in FindLogicalChildrenOfType<T>(item))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For Windows Forms you can use something similar to find all checkboxes:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindAllControlsOfType<T>(Control parent) where T : Control
{
    if (parent != null)
    {
        foreach (var control in parent.Controls)
        {
             if (control is T)
             {
                 yield return (T)control;
             }

             foreach (var childOfChild in FindAllControlsOfType<T>(control as Control))
             {
                 yield return childOfChild;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this approach, make sure all the checkboxes under the root objects are the ones you want! For example, if there are two sets of checkboxes and your root object is the form, you'll cast too wide a net.  Also, I think he wanted to test for more than one checkbox checked.